# Django error during template rendering. Reverse for 'name' with arguments '(",)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, django-urls

I am working with my first Django project, and I now I have some mistakes I don't understand at all! Yesterday I created 2 forms: one of them was working, and the data from the second one was not saved to the database. I was trying to fix this problem, but now both of them are not working, and I even have the same problem with one of my old templates. Could you please tell me what my mistakes are and how I can fix them?

This is the part of my views.py:

```
def listing(request):
    users_list = Person.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(users_list, 14) 
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'friends_plans/list.html', {"users": users})

def add_wish_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Wish_listForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.person = request.user
            newform.save()
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = Wish_listForm()
    return render(request, 'friends_plans/add_wish_list.html', {'form': form})

def add_comment(request, wish_list_id):
    person = request.user
    wish_list = get_object_or_404(Wish_list, pk=wish_list_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Comment_to_wish_listForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newform=form.save(commit=False)
            newform.person = request.user
            newform.comment_to = wish_list
            wish_list.person = person
            newform.save()
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = Comment_to_wish_listForm()
    context_dict = {'form': form, 'wish_list': wish_list}
    return render(request, 'friends_plans/add_comment.html', {'context_dict':  context_dict})
```

This is my urls.py:

```
app_name = 'friends_plans'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), # start page
url(r'^users/$', views.listing, name='listing'),
url(r'^(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/wish_list/$', views.wish_list,    name='wish_list'),
url(r'^(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.user, name='user'),
url(r'^(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<day_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.day, name='day'),
url(r'^add_wish_list/$', views.add_wish_list, name='add_wish_list'),
url(r'^(?P<wish_list_id>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.comment, name='comment'),
url(r'^(?P<wish_list_id>[0-9]+)/comment/add/$', views.add_comment,   name='add_comment'),
]
```

This is list.html:

```
{% extends 'friends_plans/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
    {% block title %} Users {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        <div id ="left">
            <div id="toptitle"> Friends' Plans members:</div>
            <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Photo</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Occupation</th>
                        <th>Days</th>
                        <th>Places</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for person in users %}
                      <tr>
                        <td><span> <img class="small_cat" src={% static  'images/cat3.jpg' %} /> </span></td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'friends_plans:user' user.pk  %}">{{ person.username|upper }}</a></span></td>
                        <td><span>Student at {{   person.place_of_work_or_study}}</span></td>
                        <td>{{person.day_set.all.count}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.wish_list_set.all.count}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
            <div class="pagination">
                <div id="listing">
                    <span class="step-links">
                        {% if users.has_previous %}
                            <a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number  }}">previous</a>
                        {% endif %}

                        <span class="current">
                            Page {{ users.number }} of {{  users.paginator.num_pages }}.
                        </span>

                        {% if users.has_next %}
                            <a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number  }}">next</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

This is add_wish_list.html:

```
{% extends 'friends_plans/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add a wish_list</h1>
<form method="post"  action="/friends_plans:add_wish_list/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add wish_list" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is add_comment.html:

```
{% extends 'friends_plans/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Add a wish_list</h1>
<form method="post"  action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I understand that the problem connected with urls, but I don't understand what it is, and why everything was fine with list.html before as I did't change it!

Comment: Did you make changes to `friends_plans/base.html`?

Comment: You should pass the action as `{% url "friends_plans:add_wish_list" %}`. You also don't need to pass a nested dictionary `{'context_dict': context_dict}` simply pass `context_dict`

Comment: Thanks! No, I didn't change anything in my friends_plans/base.html file.

Answer (score 2):

In list.html, you have `{% url 'friends_plans:user' user.pk %}` but your variable is called `person`, not `user`.

Comment: I think 'user' is from 'def user' (in views.py). And it worked with user.pk before. I think the problem is somewhere in 'def add_comment'

Comment: That comment doesn't make sense at all. You don't pass anything called "user" to the list.html template; you do pass `users`, plural, and then iterate over them with `for person in users`, so each individual user is called `person` within that loop.